# 'REQUEST' object always undefined in NestJS dynamic module

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs

I create some dynamic module(log.module.ts)

```
@Global()
@Module({})
export class LoggerModule {
 public static forRoot(options: WinstonModuleOptions = null):  DynamicModule {

 const providers = createWinstonProviders(options);
 return {
   module: LoggerModule,
   providers: providers,
   exports: providers,
  };
 }
}
```

And provider(log.provider.ts)

```
export function createWinstonProviders(loggerOpts:WinstonModuleOptions): Provider[] {
   return [
   {
    provide: 'logger',
    useFactory: () => new LoggerService(loggerOpts),
    scope: Scope.TRANSIENT
   }];
}
```

My problem is that on 'LoggerServie' I try to get 'REQUEST' object like in documantion : https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes but get always **undefined**.. (log.service.ts)

```
@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class LoggerService {
 private readonly logger: any;
 constructor(loggerOpts: WinstonModuleOptions = null, 
 @Inject(REQUEST) private readonly request?: Request) {
 this.logger = createLogger({});
 }

  test(message) {
   console.log(this.request)-----> undefined!
   return "test";
  }
}
```

My case is different from documentation because I initialise my service with new keyword and return that on 'useFactory' ...

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, for anyone have a similar issue: The problem was with the 'winston' options implemention .

This is my implementation for logger using winston,if you have any question you could ask me :

**logger.module.ts**

```
import { DynamicModule, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { WinstonModuleOptions } from './logger.interfaces';
import { createWinstonProviders } from './logger.providers';
import { LoggerService } from './logger.service';

@Module({
  providers: [LoggerService],
  exports: [LoggerService],
}) export class LoggerModule {
  public static forRoot(options?: WinstonModuleOptions): DynamicModule {
    const providers = createWinstonProviders(options);
    return {
      module: LoggerModule,
      providers: providers,
      exports: providers,
    };
  }
}
```

**logger.providers.ts**

```
  import { Provider, Scope } from '@nestjs/common';
  import { WinstonModuleOptions } from './logger.interfaces';

  export function createWinstonProviders(loggerOptions: WinstonModuleOptions): Provider[] {
  return [
    {
      provide: 'loggerOptions',
      useValue: loggerOptions || null,
      scope: Scope.TRANSIENT
    },
  ];
}
```

**logger.service.ts**

```
 import * as winston from 'winston';
    import { Injectable, Scope, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { REQUEST } from '@nestjs/core';
    import { Request } from 'express';
    import { WinstonModuleOptions } from './logger.interfaces';
    import { defaultLoggerOptions } from './logger.constants';

    @Injectable({
      scope: Scope.TRANSIENT
    })
    export class LoggerService {
      private name: string;

      constructor(@Inject('loggerOptions') private readonly loggerOptions: WinstonModuleOptions, @Inject(REQUEST) private readonly request: Request) {
        this.name = loggerOptions.name;
        winston.loggers.add(this.loggerOptions.name, loggerOptions.options || defaultLoggerOptions());
      }

      private logMessage(message, level) {
        const logger = winston.loggers.get(this.name);
        if (logger) {
          logger.log({
            level,
            message: message
          })
        }
      }

      error(message: string) {
        this.logMessage(message, 'error');
      }

      log(message: string) {
        this.logMessage(message, 'info');
      }

      warn(message: string) {
        this.logMessage(message, 'warn');
      }

      info(message: string) {
        this.logMessage(message, 'info');
      }
    }
```

**logger.interfaces.ts**

```
import { LoggerOptions } from 'winston';

export type WinstonModuleOptions = { options: LoggerOptions, name: string };
```

**logger.interfaces.ts**

```
import * as winston from 'winston';

export const defaultLoggerOptions = () => ({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console({
      format: winston.format.combine(
        winston.format.colorize(), winston.format.simple())
    })
  ],
});

export const loggerOptions = (logGroupName: string, logStreamName: string, format: string = 'simple', level: string = 'error') =>
  ({
    transports: [
      new winston.transports.Console({
        format: format === 'json' ? winston.format.combine(
          winston.format.colorize(),
          winston.format.json()
        ) : winston.format.combine(
          winston.format.colorize(),
          winston.format.simple()
        )
      })
    ]
  });
```

and...you can use that in any other module in your project.

in your **module file** you add the LoggerModule in 'import':

```
  LoggerModule.forRoot({
  options: loggerOptions('user', 'user', 'json', 'error'), name: 'user'
})
```

Then, in your controller/service you get the logger object in constructor using dependency injection:

```
constructor(private readonly logger: LoggerService ) { }
```